Curve448 ECC parameters for use with OpenSSL
I need to be able to deterministically generate (and re-generate) private-public ECC key pairs curve448 for ECDH from human-friendly passphrases (not necessarily human-memorable, just easy to type in), and I'm using the OpenSSL libraries. OpenSSL doesn't include curve448 as a standard named curve, nor does it have facilities for deterministically generating ECC keys built in, but https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography provides examples of manually computing a public key from a private key given a curve, and of constructing a custom curve. So, I have gotten as far as using PBKDF2 (which is available in OpenSSL) to convert an input passphrase into a 56-byte private key--but then I need to provide all of the group parameters for  EC_GROUP_new_curve_GFp, EC_POINT_set_affine_coordinates_GFp and EC_GROUP_set_generator in binary / hexadecimal form:

a, b, and p from the equation y^2 mod p = x^3 +ax + b mod p
The order of the group.
The x and y coordinates of the generator for the group.

Where can I find these? Or, alternatively, how can I calculate them and verify that I have done so correctly?

Curve448 is traditionally computed in Edwards form.  Now, that curve is isomorphic to some curve in Weierstrass form (that is, to some a, b, p), even then, there would be a nontrivial mapping from the resulting point in Weierstrass form back to Edwards form (which is what everyone expects)

@poncho Edited to fix it. What everybody else expects is not a big deal, as this will only be used between a closed set of devices, not to interact with the internet at large. But if there's another curve I could use with OpenSSL that provides a similar degree of strength to curve 448, that would also solve my problem.

If you're looking for X448, OpenSSL does support that, just not with the standard EC code.  There's documentation for doing what you want with the PKEY code.

@bk2204 That makes sense, but I think this is more about constructing the PKEY in the first place (which is probably why you made this a comment, so this just to clarify). Note that coding questions should be asked on [so] so answers should be about the calculations themselves, possibly augmented with the required code.

@poncho+ most everybody uses Edwards for signature (EdDSA rather than ECDSA) and Montgomery for Bernstein's X-only form of ECDH (X448 as bk2204 says). But if you really want the non-interoperable Weierstrass form, it is published in NIST SP800-186

Do not use PBKDF2 for stretching of the passphrase. Use a memory-hard KDF, such as Argon2 or scrypt. PBKDF2 is considerably more vulnerable to GPUs, FPGAs, and ASICs.
